# Copy specific column and rows value to new column with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a csv file like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwUuK.jpg) with delimiter pipe (|). Actually, I want to create the third column because I only have `column A` and `column B`.
The question is how to create the third column with windows batch script?

**Input**

```
    FoodCode | FoodName 
   ----------+----------
    MB001    | Meatball 
    SP001    | Spaghetti
```

**Output**

```
    FoodCode | FoodName  | ExternalKey
   ----------+-----------+------------
    MB001    | Meatball  |  MB001
    SP001    | Spaghetti |  SP001
```

Comment: how do you plan to brute force an excel file? Or are you referring to a csv file?

Comment: *If you are using Excel* **and** *your table uses one of Excel's proprietary formats* (**.xls, xlsx, xlsm, etc**) then I would suggest using VBA instead of a batch file. Otherwise, you might find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197600/add-columns-into-a-csv-file-using-batch-file or in a related search

Comment: @GerhardBarnard i refer to csv file, all rows value from third column always same with in first column

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious thanks for reference, actually it's different thing. From that url create new column but all rows value empty

Comment: I update csv file, it use pipe delimiter

Comment: I disagree.  It is only a different thing if you are looking for a solution that you can copy and paste. If you're looking for a solution that demonstrates how to add a column and assign be values to reach row in that column, then it is exactly the same thing and you should go back and look at the accepted answer. .....  A pipe delimiter ?  What the...  Then it isn't a CSV

Comment: Got it, i figured it out after change else condition. I will put my script in below, thanks again for the insight. @ProfoundlyOblivious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code to duplicate from specific column and copy entire rows value.

```
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion Set Row=0 ( 
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=" %%A in (food.csv) do (
    Set /A Row+=1
    If !Row! lss 2 (Rem new header
      echo %%A^|ExternalKey
    ) Else (Rem insert duplicate values
      echo %%A^|%%A
    )   
) 
) >"food.tmp" 
move /y "food.tmp" "food.csv"
```